# Is there a way to declaratively push updates to an observable after it has been defined?

Tags: system.reactive, rx-swift

I'm exploring Rx, and I wanted to see if I could declaratively define the input *and* output of some UI element in terms of each other, before this element's component is initialized.

This is what it would look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var child: ButtonComponent!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonInput = PublishSubject<()>()
        let buttonOutput = buttonInput
            .scan(0) { count, _ in
                count + 1
            }
            .map { $0.description }

        self.child = ButtonComponent(
            button: self.button,
            input: buttonInput,
            output: buttonOutput
        )
    }
}

class ButtonComponent {
    weak var button: UIButton!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(button: UIButton, input: PublishSubject<()>, output: Observable<String>) {
        self.button = button

        output
            .subscribeNext { string in
                button.setTitle(string, forState: .Normal)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        button.rx_tap
            .subscribeNext {
                input.onNext($0)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I'm using the PublishSubject to push updates to the input stream, which is imperative and advised against. Does Rx provide a way to somehow add sequences to an already running observable?

Comment: Answer to your last question is yes, by using `Observable.Merge`. Though I'm not quite sure how to apply it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the answer seems to be no. Simply because if you want to add a sequence to an already running observable, it's a mutation. And there is no declarative way to do a mutation.

I looked at a javascript library called cycle.js which does exactly the same thing, and they solved it in a similar way, with a ReplaySubject.

The only thing you can do is make it look a bit nicer by doing

```
button.rx_tap
    .subscribe(input)
```

Instead of

```
button.rx_tap
    .subscribeNext {
        input.onNext($0)
    }
```

Comment: This isn't true. The `merge` operator will allow you to add to an already running observable.

Comment: `merge` returns a new observable, it can't mutate an observable.

Comment: Yes, but if you insert the merge into the query at compile-time you can then insert values at run-time.

Comment: The two sequences that are to be merged have to already be there though. The problem here is that I want to define `buttonOutput` in terms of `buttonInput`, before I even have the input of the button.